# Are western martial arts on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Say, I had a question about fencing.  Would that be on topic?

What about rapier fighting?

What about medieval sword work for re-enactment?

Answer (score 13):

Yes.

As long as we draw the line on re-enactment, versus showmanship (Renaissance Faire-type fighting), since that falls under the category of theatre.

The western arts, which are now experiencing a regain in popularity, are just as interesting, and I would certainly love to see questions about rapier fighting and differences between Spanish and Italian techniques, as well as Savate and even Bartitsu.

Comment: i agree with you 100%

Comment: What about "Olympic" Fencing?

Comment: @noahz please define Olympic fencing for me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencing#Olympic_fencing as opposed to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_fencing

Comment: Oy.. The sport of fencing.. I would argue that no, it does not qualify, because it is a sport, and it has rules. By the same token, I would argue that Boxing and UFC do not qualify, either.

Comment: I see MMA questions on here. Isn't that a sport, with rules?

Comment: I'm not sure it applies. People train for olympic fencing very differently than they train for classical fencing, and people train for MMA tournaments very differently than they would train to use MMA for self-defense. I would dislike with seeing questions related to tournament MMA -- but I am not judge and jury :)

Comment: Someone told me about the new Sports StackExchange in Beta, so I'm going to direct "Olympic" fencing questions there.

Comment: People train for Tae Kwon Do tournament differently then they would to use if for self defense--gaming the rules by holding their guard out and down to make sweeping kicks to the head difficult, and the like. I'd go with the rules of sport fencing off-topic, but the handling of the epee (or even the foil) on-topic.

Comment: I see no reason to draw a line between combat sport and martial art for this site. Why limit?